# undefined value for parameter in directive using controllerAs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm almost too embarrased to ask this, but after hours trying I can´t find the cause for this issue.

Simple directive, just passing a parameter one-way. If I use $scope in the controller the parameter's value is in there, but when I switch to controllerAs and bindToController to get rid of $scope, then the parameter is undefined.

This is my code and also the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/n3afpu3L/).

```
<my-directive param="foo"></my-directive>

angular
    .module("app",[])
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            param: '@'
        },
        controller: function() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.foo = vm.param + ' foo2';
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '{{vm.foo}}'    
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using out of date syntax - `bindToController` has changed - see below

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        // **********************
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            param: '@'
        },
        controller: function() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.foo = vm.param + ' foo2';
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template: '{{vm.foo}}'    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Simon, but in my fiddle I'm using angular 1.2, it should be working fine I think.

Comment: do you want to set your fiddle up with the code the question, rather than the earlier iteration?

Comment: ok, I tested with 1.4 and it works as you said; I did test it that way previously but apparently some mistake in my build was not updating libraries from angular 1.2 to 1.4